# Logic Python task with bitwise operators

Tags: python, algorithm, logic, bit, bitwise-operators

I have a very specific task to complete and I am honestly lost in it. The goal is to define function in Python, that would remove all 1s in binary input that do not have any 1 next to it. I will show you in example.

Let's have input `0b11010` -–> the output of this would be `0b11000`. Another example `0b10101` --> output would be `Ob00000`.

The real twist is that I cannot use any for/while loop, import any library or use zip, lists, map etc. The function needs to be defined purely using [bitwise operations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-bitwise-operators/) and nothing else.

I was already trying to implement the concepts of operations, but those were only blind shots and got nowhere. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To break down the condition mathematically, the i-th bit of the output should be `1` if and only if:

1. The `i`-th bit of the input is `1`.
2. And either the `(i-1)`-th bit or the `(i+1)`-th bit of the input is also `1`.

Logically the condition is `input[i] and (input[i-1] or input[i+1])` if the input is a bit vector. If the input is simply a number, indexing can be emulated with bit shifting and masking, giving this code:

```
def remove_lonely_ones(b):
    return b & ((b << 1) | (b >> 1))
```

Testing shows that it works both on your examples and on edge cases:

```
print("{: 5b}".format(remove_lonely_ones(0b11111))) # prints 11111
print("{: 5b}".format(remove_lonely_ones(0b11010))) # prints 11000
print("{: 5b}".format(remove_lonely_ones(0b11011))) # prints 11011
print("{: 5b}".format(remove_lonely_ones(0b10101))) # prints 0
print("{: 5b}".format(remove_lonely_ones(0b00000))) # prints 0
```